# Travar código form ao abrir modal

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Possuo um modal boostrap que funciona perfeitamente, chamo ele no c# code-behind, dessa forma:

```html
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "myModal", "$(function() {openModalExclusao();});", true);
```

E essa é a função pra abrir:

```js
function openModalExclusao() {
  $("#modalexclusao").modal('show');
}
```

Porém eu preciso que ele pare a execução do código quando o modal for aberto, e só continuar quando ele for fechado, dessa forma ele executa o código depois deste abrindo o modal normal, preciso igual é em um projeto desktop, só que que no ASP.NET. Como posso proceder ?

Explicação edit.
Eu vou fazer uma requisição de senha, por exemplo tal usuário vai excluir, mas ele só pode excluir com a senha do administrador, eu preciso verificar se a senha confere, e se a senha conferir continuar a execução do código:

```js
if (senha.existesenha == 1) {
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "myModal", "$(function() {openModalExclusao();});", true);
  if (senha.confere == 1) {
    clsdb.ExecutaSQL("delete musculos where id =" + ID);
  }
}
```

Só que antes de ter o retorno do confere,ele ja continua o código e não executa o delete. Porque o retorno do confere, está no click do button do modal.

Comment: Mariana, primeiro devemos entender que, o js roda no cliente. Sabendo disso, sabemos tb que não tem como ele parar a execução de um código.  O que você pode fazer é chamar uma função que por sua vez dispara uma requisição ajax para o server, e ai continuar o seu trabalho normalmente...

Comment: @DiegoSantos tem algum exemplo para que eu possa entender, e saber incluir conforme minhas necessidades?

Comment: Bom, não conheço o code behind, mas, se possível, pare a execução do que está fazendo no momento em que registra esse .js. Depois, você deve usar o evento de fechamento do modal para requisitar um serviço por exemplo, que continue seu processamento.  Veja o evento: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363802/bind-a-function-to-twitter-bootstrap-modal-close

Comment: Lembrando que, isso te sugiro sem saber a sua necessidade, talvez sabendo dela, possamos ajudar melhor

Comment: Vou analisar o exemplo que me passou, e vou atualizar meu código para minha necessidade.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta, para que você possa entender, lembrando que este modal está na master, pois vou precisar chamá-lo em todos os forms, para não haver redundância no código, optei por colocar na master.

Comment: Você pode usar o evento de fechamento somente na página que precisa deste funcionamento. Independente do modal estar na master, ele vai carregar no DOM da mesma forma...

Comment: Não entendi muito bem @DiegoSantos, preciso parar o código enquanto o modal não é fechado ele não deve continuar.

Comment: Preciso ver o código inteiro do C#, mas pelo pouco que vi vc pode dar um return, ou algo do gênero. E depois chame uma página no ajax que termine o que não foi feito. Aí é uma questão de lógica mesmo. Precisamos do fonte mesmo!

Comment: Eu fiz uma função e chamo ela quando a senha é conferida, porém como pego esse retorno no codebehind? Esse código está na master, preciso do retorno em outro form.